# Align Text Vertically on top material UI <Textfield />

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have this component

```
const styles = theme => ({
  height: {
    height: '20rem',
  },
});

class Foo extends React.component { 
    ...

    <TextField
      InputProps={{ classes: { root: this.props.classes.height } }}
      label="Kittens"
      placeholder="Meooow"
      fullWidth={true}
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      notched={true}
      value={this.state.kittyCat}
      onChange={event => this.onChangeKittens(event)}
      multiline={true} />
}
```

The height is applied, making the `<TextField />` bigger. However, I want to align the text vertically in the `<TextField />`.

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to align the text vertically in the?

Comment: @Nimsrules Ups. forgot the closing ticks

Answer (score 1):

You can align the text vertically using flex, like:

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

However, Material-UI TextField create a `div` container, which has two inner elements - another `div` and a `label`.

The `label` part has `absolute` position by default (For the animated label effect), which might make it difficult to achieve what you want without some hairy css overrides.

A better approach might be to set the styles on the `TextField` container. You can do this using the material-style system as in your example code:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    height: '20rem',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

class Foo extends React.component { 
    ...
    <form className={classes.container}>
       <TextField
         ... />
    </form>
}
```

Update: I've added a [Demo on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-1liyo?fontsize=14).
Update: Fixed brackets

[image: Edit Material-UI TextField vertical align]

Check [this](https://medium.com/@js_tut/the-complete-css-flex-box-tutorial-d17971950bdc) out for more about flexbox

Comment: OP wants to 'vertically' align the text. They need `align-items: center` added to the flex container

Comment: my bad, i was missing `flex-direction: column;` Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to change the `flex-direction`. Simply applying `align-items: center` will do the trick.

Comment: That is not working... It sets the Textfield to the top, but not the text in the textfield

Comment: `Nimsrules` both options will have the same effect. Changing flex direction will change the flex main axis, so it's basically using 2 different attributes for the same thing.

Comment: `Stophface` - Update: I've added a Demo on sandbox.